# How to reset to Inellij keybindings?

Tags: intellij-idea

I recently changed my Keymappings.  I went to top menu Intellij IDEA > Preferences > Keymap > Keymaps and selected "visual studio".

I want to revert back to the keybindings I had, which I configured during installation of intellij.  I think they called it "IDEA keybindings".  I do not see this as an option.  I tried every Keymap in the dropdown and none of them match the installation keymap.

How do I get back to the IDEA keybindings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the OS, the default keymap is called **Default** for Windows and Linux and **Mac OS X 10.5+** for Mac.

It corresponds to the [official PDF keymap reference](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf).

Comment: That one is pretty close.  I'll go ahead and use it.  Somehow I ended up with F9 mapped to resume program on original install.  Using this it switched me to CMD + ALT + R.

Comment: I have the same problem. Default is gone from the list.

Comment: @CsabaTenkes Default keymaps are in bold now, all the customized keymaps will be child nodes in the tree in normal font, does it help? https://i.imgur.com/AXBFami.png.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings -> Search Keymap -> click on keymap and besides that you see a gear icon, click on it, you should be able to see an option, to reset to default